# Google is displaying wrong business address

Tags: google

When you search for my client's company, in the search listings in Google it displays the wrong address. In fact, the address displayed is not relevant to my clients company.

What is the best method to ensure Google displays the correct address for the company? Is there a meta tag I can add into the website?

The website is
{{ removed }}

```
{{ removed }} is not the correct address
```

Comment: There are two things I would do. Find the page(s) that have the company address and do a Fetch as Google within the Google Search Console for these pages. It will take a few days so be patient. Then I would investigate using schema.org mark-up for the company address.

Comment: @closetnoc, Google will only return the schema address for searches that do not include national or local search results. It's likely that frosty's search is returning local search results, and it is these that are wrong, since he/she has not mentioned the use of schema. Frosty, please leave a comment here with your site address so people can assist you further.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thanks!! Good to know. I have not been keeping up on that. It would also be good to know the OP;s search queries too- just to be sure.

Comment: hi thanks for you comments. I've added the domain name which i'll remove in a few days

Answer (score 2):

As I suspected, Your NAP (NAME ADDRESS PHONE) lacks consistency which in turn will display incorrect information and can actually work negatively towards your national and local rankings on Google.

Over the last few years Google has adapted its algorithm to return more favourable results for local and national customers across the country. Google's new algorithm is an extension and looks for external sources to establish NAP and reputation through reviews.

To ensure that your rankings are achieving full potential your going to have to fix your citations, telling people your business is here, and then on other websites a completely different address will lose you brownie points with Google.

Your going to have to pay someone or spend a lot of time amending 'EXTERNAL' sources with correct and current data. You should also use this opportunity to add value to those citations with unique text and pictures, this will make the pages more valuable, and may increase leads.

Good practice when correcting or making citations is:

- Ensure that you use your full company name, i.e bits and bobs LTD, not bits & bobs. Use whatever name is used on gov uk, and company check.
- Ensure that you use an addressed registered with royal mail, do not add department names to added as these are internal addresses and likely confuse Google.
- Use one telephone number if possible.
- MOST IMPORTANT make sure every citation is exactly the same as the others in regards of NAP.

You should first start by amending your [Google Plus page](https://plus.google.com/110067424862476081233/about), as this is the most important factor.

You should then start to fix others, this is only an example as time is money and I don't have the time to list every site your business is mentioned on,

- [Cylex](http://london.cylex-uk.co.uk/company/topland-group-plc-17005694.html)
- [Kompass](http://gb.kompass.com/c/topland-group-plc/gb25085219/)
- [Standard](http://local.standard.co.uk/company/437960340103168)
- [118](http://www.118118.com/lee-green/investment-companies/284486-topland-group-plc.html)
- [Thomson Local](http://www.thomsonlocal.com/Topland-Group-PLC/447251/020%207493%203373/)

You should also amend problems with the NAPW (Name Address Phone Website), some citations are pointing to .co.uk and some the .com (choose one, and stick with it).

NOTE: Please note that I've only skimmed the through the surface of NATIONAL AND LOCAL SEO. Your going to have to do a lot of reading or seek professional assistance. We the members of Pro Webmasters Community are here to help should you encounter any more problems along the way.